# Unsupported options found for 'hudi'

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, apache-hudi

I'm testing Apache Hudi with Flink SQL Client on Yarn cluster. When I'm trying to create a Hudi catalog ([like described](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/sql_ddl/#create-catalog)) I'm facing an error telling me that `hive.conf.dir` and `mode` options are not supported.

```
org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.SqlExecutionException: Could not execute SQL statement.
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.executeOperation(LocalExecutor.java:211) ~[flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeOperation(CliClient.java:625) ~[flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.callOperation(CliClient.java:447) ~[flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.lambda$executeStatement$1(CliClient.java:332) [flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeStatement(CliClient.java:325) [flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeFile(CliClient.java:314) [flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeInitialization(CliClient.java:240) [flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.openCli(SqlClient.java:135) [flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.start(SqlClient.java:95) [flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:187) [flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:161) [flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to create catalog 'hoodie_catalog'.

Catalog options are:
'catalog.path'='/my/path'
'hive.conf.dir'='/etc/hive/conf'
'mode'='hms'
'type'='hudi'
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createCatalog(FactoryUtil.java:292) ~[flink-table_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.createCatalog(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1292) ~[flink-table_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1122) ~[flink-table_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.lambda$executeOperation$3(LocalExecutor.java:209) ~[flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.ExecutionContext.wrapClassLoader(ExecutionContext.java:88) ~[flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.executeOperation(LocalExecutor.java:209) ~[flink-sql-client_2.11-1.14.6.jar:1.14.6]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unsupported options found for 'hudi'.

Unsupported options:

hive.conf.dir
mode

Supported options:

catalog.path
default-database
property-version
```

Is there some versions incompatibility or I should look for another Hudi version doc page ?

**I'm using:**

- Flink 1.14.6
- hudi-flink1.14-bundle_2.11-0.11.1.jar

Launching Flink Cli this way:

```
flink/bin/sql-client.sh embedded -j /home/otarie/flink-1.14.6/opt/hudi-flink1.14-bundle_2.11-0.11.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. I couldn't find the required version on the official website link, so I downloaded an older version. With the bundle version `hudi-flink1.14-bundle-0.14.1.jar`, the error disappeared.